# how to put txt file to specific line of the second txt file

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filewriter

I have 2 files, one is new.txt and second is template.txt
i need to put new.txt to the 6 line of template.txt and don't understand how to do that.
let's show you what i already have!

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File(".");

        String source = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "new.txt";
        String dest = dir.getCanonicalPath() + File.separator + "template.txt";

        File fin = new File(source);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(dest,true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        String aLine = null;
        while((aLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            out.write(aLine);
            out.newLine();
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: so what is going wrong?

Comment: @ScaryWombat problem is that i don't understand how to put text from new.txt to template.txt (6 line)

Comment: So this is being `inserted` after line 6?  Not appended?  If that is the case you will need to open both files and write to a new file.

Comment: @GermanVaranytsya I have an idea, `file.readLine` to `List<String> listOne` then go through this list copy everything from `listOne` to `List<String> listTwo` but in this time when you reach index 5 (line six of file) append what you need from second file to `listTwo` and after that continue copying `listOne` to `listTwo`

Answer (score 4):

Files don't have an "insert" operation. You can't simply write something to the middle of the file. Writes happen at a given offset, and they override whatever is already there.

So you need to create a temp file, copy lines 1-5 of `new.txt` into it. Then write line 6 from the template, followed by the rest of `new.txt`. Once you're done, delete `new.txt` and rename the temp file to `new.txt`.

If the files a are guaranteed to be small, you can replace the temp file with an in-memory buffer.

Comment: i mean that i want all text from 1 file insert into 2 file 6 line

Comment: Okay, that doesn't change the solution. After writing the first 5 lines of the template to the temp file, write all of new.txt to the temp file. Skip any newline (`\n`) characters `new.txt` might contain if you want it in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo code to comment above:

```java
File fileOne = new File("new.txt");
File fileTwo = new File("template.txt");

List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>();

String s = "";

while((s = fileOne.readLine()) != null){
  listOne.add(s);
}

for(int i = 0; i < listOne.size(); i++){
  if(i == 5){
    String s2 = "";
    while((s2 = fileTwo.readLine()) != null){
      listTwo.add(s);
    }
  }
  listTwo.add(listOne.get(i));
}
```

Like I said this is only pseudo code, so may not work, but that will be good exercise for you to make it work. I hope you understand the idea behind it.

PS. of course after you do that, you have to write all data from `listTwo` to file which you want.

Comment: by the way i was thinking, do i need 2 arrays? maybe Array list should be used only in case of text file where i need to find this 6 line?

Comment: I was not thinking about it to long, so for sure there is better way to do it, but I wanted only to show you idea. How you implement it its totally up to you.

Comment: idea is nice i think, i will try it now